# Фильтр плохих слов python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня проблема с моим кодом. Здесь написан мой *недо фильтр* плохих слов, который я еще буду дорабатывать. Я не могу разобраться с 1 вещью: если в тексте есть запрещенное слово (у нас черт), то оно заменит все его вхождения, в том числе в словах чертеж, чертильный и т.д. У меня не получается ничего с этим сделать. Только, пожалуйста, не пишите мне регулярные выражения, я в них ничего не понимаю.

```
import random

chars = ["*","#","%","&","?","@"]
bw  = ["черт", "дурак"]
txt = 'Ты черт нарисовал чертеж?'.replace('  ', ' ').lower().split(' ')
print(txt)

for word in txt:
    if word in bw:
        i = ''.join(random.sample(chars, len(word)))
        txt = [x.replace(word, i) for x in txt]

res = ' '.join(txt)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш скрипт при нахождении плохого слова в тексте `if word in bw:`, проходится ещё раз по всем словам в списке и заменяет их часть `txt = [x.replace(word, i) for x in txt]`, этого делать не нужно.

Я немного переписал ваш цикл, чтобы можно было доступаться к определённому элементу списка (слову), используя  функцию `range`. Теперь, когда вы найдёте элемент, который подходит вашему условию - вы можете его заменить.

```
for i in range(len(txt)):
    if txt[i] in bw:
        txt[i] = ''.join(random.sample(chars, len(txt[i])))
```

> ты *?&# нарисовал чертеж?

Работает только при полном совпадении матерного слова.